# Export worksheets as separate files by using userform and browse for file path

Tags: vba, excel

I know export worksheets as separate files has been asked before too. I checked those answers but I couldn't find solution for my problems, hence asked new question.

Code :

```
Private Sub cancel_button_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub export_button_Click()
Dim FileExtStr As String
Dim FileFormatNum As Long
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim xWb As Workbook
Dim FolderName As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set xWb = Application.ThisWorkbook
DateString = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss")
FolderName = xWb.Path & "\" & xWb.Name & " " & DateString
MkDir FolderName

For Each xWs In xWb.Worksheets
    xWs.Copy
        If xlsx = True Then
            FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
            Unload Me
        ElseIf xlsm = True Then
                FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
                Unload Me
        ElseIf xls = True Then
            FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
            Unload Me
        ElseIf xlsb = True Then
            FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
            Unload Me
        End If
    xFile = FolderName & "\" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name & FileExtStr
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs xFile, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Next

MsgBox "You can find the files in " & FolderName
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Userform :
[image]

With above code and userform, I am able to work perfectly. I don't know the FileFormatNum for `csv` and `txt`, hence I could'nt create if loop for those two fileformat.

I need your help. I need to create a combobox in userform specifying around 15 fileformats. And also, a file browse button to select the export folder. User does both the selection(file format and location of folder for export).
I have created the userform:
[image]

1. On click of **browse** button, a **select folder** dialog box should open up from which user selects a folder to export the worksheets. The path of the folder should be displayed in the textbox beside **browse** button.
2. The combobox will display 15 fileformats. On selecting any one from the list, the sheets will be exported with that file extension.

How can I do it? I am not able to do it. Please anyone. Just give me a push and I'll finish it.

Answer (score 1):

FileFormatNum for csv and txt are here.

- csv : 20
- txt (UniCode) : 42

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/xlfileformat-enumeration-excel

For eaisly finding xlfileformat just Go to the object browser in the VB window (Press F2) and then type xlFileFormat in the Search Text box.